# pulling a variable from a bracket section

Tags: java

I have got a while statement which contains many different if statements which add up the value from an array. The value in the array has been pulled from a file.

```
int variable 1
int variable 2
while(scanner.next()) {
 if variable 1 {

 }
if variable 2 {

}

}
```

The values add up for each line and display the total for that line only. I want the total values from each line to add up to give an overall total.

The problem is when I try to use variable 1 or 2 after the closing while bracket, I get an error. I presume this is because it is not in the same block as the while statement? How do I solve this problem?

This is similar to what I need:

```
 int variable 1
 int variable 2
 while(scanner.next()) {
 if variable {

 }
 if variable 2 {

 }

 }
int overall total = variable 1 + variable 2;
System.out.println(overalltotal);
```

Comment: from the pseudo code sample you have shown (1 and 2 are defined right before while{...} and total is right after it) it should work. Please post a sample that really reproduces the error.

Comment: Please read the Java tutorial [Lesson: Language Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html).

Comment: For the overalltotal, variables 1 + 2 displays the error " Cannot be resolved as a variable"

Comment: @Breaker For the record, variable names cannot contain white spaces

Comment: Thanks for tip. By habit I don't use white space but if I ever do I will know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets in Java, defines a `block`. Each **block** has its own `scope` and inherits the scope of the **parent block**.

Therefore, when you define a new variable inside a block, it would only be *alive* (or *accessed*) on that block's scope (and its child scopes), and not by external scopes.

Please, take a look at this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html), specially at the ***Local Variables*** section.

### Example

---

This **won't** work:

```
if(something) { //Start of if scope

    //We create someVar on the if scope
    int someVar = 0;

} //End of if scope

System.out.println(someVar); //You can't access someVar! You are out of the scope
```

This **will** work:

```
//We create someVar on the method's scope
int someVar = 0

if(something) { //Start of if scope

    //This "if scope" is a child scope, so it inherits parent's scope
    //Can access the parent scope
    someVar = 2;

} //End of if scope

System.out.println(someVar); //Can access someVar! It wasn't defined on a child scope
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum as you go instead of after the fact.

```
int total = 0;

while(scanner.next()) {
 if int variable 1 {
    total += variable 1
 }
 if variable 2 {
    total += variable 2
 }

 }
System.out.println(total);
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile, so isn't a very good example for someone who appear to be struggling with basics ...

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried to this but i get the same error as the println is outside the while block.

Comment: @DavidPostill As pseudo code this is perfectly fine, which is what he was providing (as in the original question).